# Where are Mozc settings?

Tags: ibus, japanese, mozc

Here is how the Mozc settings dialog is supposed to look like:

[image]

But I can't find it anywhere in Ubuntu, for instance here is the iBus dialog (note how Preferences is greyed out):

[image]

Where to find the Mozc settings?

There are no mozc* executables on my PATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to enter the config dialog your mentioned manually, try:

```
/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog
```

The Preferences bug in ibus-setup is because of meta-data missing.

Check Comment 1: http://code.google.com/p/mozc/issues/detail?id=169

Answer (score 1):

## Steps

To access the Mozc menu:

1. Select Mozc input mode by:

   - Hold <kbd>Super</kbd> and press <kbd>Space</kbd> as many times as to select Mozc option, or;
   - click on: `IBus` (at `GNOME Status Menu`) > `Japanese (Mozc)`.
2. Again, click on `Gnome Status Menu` > `IBuz` > `tools` > `Properties` > `Mozc Settings` window.

## Requirements

I'm using:

- SO: ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- IMF: ibus 1.5.17
- IME: mozc 2.20.2673.102

## Screenshot

Ibus-mozc settings access by menu:

[image: Ibus-mozc settings access by menu]