# Where are mozc settings in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 19.04, japanese, mozc

I want to modify the Mozc settings.

**Problem:** Clicking the gear at the right of `Japanese (Mozc)` has no effect:

[image]

[On previous versions of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169835/where-are-mozc-settings), a workaround was to run `/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog` from command line, but that executable does not exist anymore (the `mozc_server` and `mozc_renderer` in the same folder do not seem to do anything when run with the same argument).

Is there a workaround to open the Mozc settings? They are supposed to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `mozc-utils-gui` to have `mozc_tool`

```
sudo apt-get install mozc-utils-gui
```

before running `/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (18.04) uses IBUS to be the IMF (Input method framework).
And it manages the IMEs (Input Method Editor), like MOZC.

## Install:

- [ibus](https://github.com/ibus/ibus): `sudo apt install ibus`.
- [mozc](https://github.com/google/mozc): `sudo apt install ibus-mozc mozc-utils-gui`.

## Navigation

To see the configuration window:

1. Click on `Gnome Status` menu (Gnome's top-left bar) > `IBus` menu (i.e. keyboard/input language selector) > Select `Japanese Mozc` input method.
2. Again, click on `Gnome Status Menu` > `IBuz` > `tools` > `Properties` > `Mozc Settings` window.

## Screenshots

[image: ibus-mozc]

## Alternatives

You can install/use another IMFs and japanese IMEs.

### IMEs

Others IMEs to substitute MOZC when typing japanese are:

- [Anthy](https://osdn.net/projects/anthy/): `sudo apt install ibus-anthy`.
- [KKC](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-kkc): `sudo apt install ibus-kkc`.
- [SKK](https://github.com/ueno/ibus-skk): `sudo apt install ibus-skk`.

### IMFs

One suggestion to substitute IBUS is FCITX:

- [Fcitx](https://fcitx-im.org): `sudo apt install fcitx`.

And you will need to install all IMEs again, like:

- `sudo apt install fcitx-mozc`.
- `sudo apt install fictx-kkc`.
- `sudo apt install fictx-skk`.

A list of IMF can be found in [List of input methods for Unix platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_Unix_platforms) and [Linux input method framework brief summary](https://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/2011/01/15/linux-input-method-brief-summary/).